# Native wifi setprofile and connecting c++

Tags: c++, wifi, wlan

Мой профиль ( через команду netsh wlan show networks) имеет вот такую кофигурацию:

```
SSID 1 : UKrtelecom_5E6B80
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
```

[image: настройки профиля с винды]

Я пробо вал засетить профиль з разными кофигурациями  authentication & encryption ({WPA2PSK, AES}, {WPA2-Personal CCMP}…)

Кусок кода:

```
void connect_to_rsnapsk(HANDLE wlanClient, WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK & entry, PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO wlan_interface) {
    const std::string authentication = "WPA2PSK";
    auto profile_xml = get_profile_xml(static_cast<std::string>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(entry.dot11Ssid.ucSSID)), authentication, "CCMP", "pass");//на самом деле тут мой пароль

    //TODO see profile template for appropriate type, reason code return "bad profile"
    DWORD reasonCode;
    const int set_profile_result = WlanSetProfile(wlanClient, &wlan_interface->InterfaceGuid, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPCWSTR>(profile_xml.c_str()), nullptr, true, nullptr, &reasonCode);
    wrap_set_profile_result(set_profile_result, reasonCode);
}
```

Имея вот такой профиль:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>UKrtelecom_5E6B80</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>UKrtelecom_5E6B80</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <autoSwitch>false</autoSwitch>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>CCMP</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial><myPass></keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

Возвращается такой ризон код:  WLAN_REASON_CODE_INVALID_PROFILE_SCHEMA.

Я также пробывал конектится через либу NativeWifi в шарпе. Сделал профиль:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>UKrtelecom_5E6B80</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <name>UKrtelecom_5E6B80</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>manual</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>CCMP</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial><myPass></keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

И попробывал за set'ить этот профиль 
wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true);
Выкидывает exception «Конфигурация подключения к сети повреждена».

Если что алгоритм авторизации у меня : DOT11_AUTH_ALGO_RSNA_PSK

Что я делаю не так, и как мне за connect'тится через профиль, хотя бы объясните как его set’ить?

Comment: Прпробуй поменять Encryption. Профиль выглядит вполне рабочим. Вместо Encryption поставь одно из: TKIP, AES, WEP

Comment: @MikePetrichenko, все три варианта все равно возвращают WLAN_REASON_CODE_INVALID_PROFILE_SCHEMA (((

Comment: Что логично. std:string - ANSI. WnalSetProfile хочет Unicode

Comment: @MikePetrichenko а каким образом вообще влияет кодировка, и если так, то как это пофиксить? все же ковертится в конце к char* "profile_xml.c_str()"

Comment: Ну как каким. ANSI - 1 байт. UNICODE - 2 байта. Строка "AB" f ANSI это последовательность байт 6566, что в UNICODE приведет к одному символу какому-нибудь японскому иероглифу. c_str() всего лишь возвращает указатель на строку, но никак не конвертирует. Пофиксить можно, к примеру, используя std::wstring

Comment: В UNICODE символы двухбайтовые. Первый байт обозначает кодовую страницу, Второй, собственно, символ в этой таблице. Т.е. строка "AB" в UNICODE будет занимать 4 байта и иметь вид 00650066.

Comment: Это в общем случае (собственно, применимом к WlanSetProfile)/ А так есть еще UTF8 (однобайтовый UNICODE). UTF16 (собственно, о котором я написал выше). И UTF32 (4 байта на символ). Его я ни разу не встречал.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko спасибо, только вы помогаете, попробую)

Comment: Да пока не за что.